Proof of Ohba's Conjecture in Graph Theory
I am studying the paper A Proof of a Conjecture of Ohba by Noel, Reed, and Wu.

I did not understand why $(1.2)$ is necessary?
I think it should be replaced with $\chi (G^{\prime}) = k-l$. Am I right?
Thank for your time.

Do you mean to ask whether (1.2) is sufficient? Your proposed modification is to strengthen the condition (1.2), which is a weird thing to suggest if you think the condition is not necessary in the first place.

@MishaLavrov: I mean why the strict inequality is also acceptable?

The stated condition is correct, though (at least for someone unfamiliar with Ohba's conjecture) it's not obvious why, and the obvious proof results in an equality in $(1.2)$ instead.
It seems at first that we want to say the following. "If, after applying the partial coloring, we are left with a graph $G'$ satisfying the conditions of Ohba's conjecture, then we may assume that it is chromatic-choosable, because $G$ was a minimal counterexample. If, additionally, the remaining list assignment $L'$ has at least $\chi(G')$ colors in every list, then we can use our assumption to $L'$-color $G'$, giving us an $L$-coloring of $G$. This is a contradiction!"
For the first step, we require $|V(G')| \le 2 \chi(G') + 1$. For the second step, we require $|L'(v)| \ge \chi(G')$ for all $v \in V(G')$. If we set $\chi(G') = k-\ell$ (where we know $\ell\ge 0$ because $\chi(G') \le \chi(G)$) then we can write these inequalities as the three conditions:
\begin{align}
   |V(G')| &\le 2(k-\ell) + 1, \tag{1.1} \\
   \chi(G') &= k-\ell, \tag{1.2${}^*$} \\
   |L'(v)| &\ge k-\ell \quad \forall v \in V(G') \tag{1.3}
\end{align}
On the other hand, if we were to relax $(1.2^*)$ to $\chi(G') \le k-\ell$, the condition in the paper, then we can't apply Ohba's conjecture to $G'$ directly; it's possible that $G'$ has more than $2\chi(G')+1$ vertices. Instead, we need the following lemma:
Lemma. Let $G'$ be a $t$-colorable graph with $|V(G')| \le 2t+1$. Assuming Ohba's conjecture for graphs with at most $|V(G')|$ vertices, $G'$ is also $t$-choosable.
Proof. Let $\chi(G') = r$ for some $r \le t$. We modify $G'$ to get a new graph $G''$ as follows:

Add edges to $G'$ until it's a complete $r$-partite graph.
Repeat the following $t-r$ times, or as long as possible: choose a vertex in a part of size $\ge 2$, and add all missing edges out of that vertex. This increases the chromatic number by $1$.

If we were able to do step 2 a total of $t-r$ times, then $G''$ is a complete $t$-partite graph on at most $2t+1$ vertices, and by Ohba's conjecture, it is $t$-choosable. If we were not able to do step 2 a total of $t-r$ times, it's because we arrived at a graph $G'' \cong K_s$ where $r \le s \le t$. Then $G''$ is $s$-choosable and in particular $t$-choosable.
Either way, $G'$ is also $t$-choosable, because $G'$ is a subgraph of $G''$. $\quad\square$
With this lemma, applied for $t = k-\ell$, we can $L'$-color $G'$ just assuming the condition $(1.2)$ in the paper (that $\chi(G') \le k-\ell$) instead of assuming $(1.2^*)$.

I want to briefly explain my thought process, because the description "someone unfamiliar with Ohba's conjecture" also applied to me, and I also went through the initial confusion of seeing that the obvious proof gives a different condition in place of $(1.2)$.
First of all, there's a key observation: although we're asking for more by stating condition $(1.2)$ as in the paper, we're not asking for something obviously impossible by the examples showing Ohba's conjecture is tight. When $\chi(G') < k-\ell$ we won't necessarily be able to prove that $G'$ is chromatic-choosable, but we also don't need it to be chromatic-choosable; we're just asking for it to be $(k-\ell)$-choosable. When I noticed this, I wrote down the exact claim we need to be true: that is, the lemma above.
I tried proving the lemma, but got nowhere, because all my initial attempts at increasing the chromatic number of $G'$ (so that Ohba's conjecture would apply to it) also increased the number of vertices. I also checked that the published version of the paper still had the same condition; I wouldn't want to waste too much time if it turned out that this was a simple typo that was fixed later!
I still doubted that this claim was true, so I went to the paper Choice number of some complete multi-partite graphs by Enomoto et al., cited in this paper as evidence that Ohba's conjecture is tight. I was hoping to find some examples that would disprove the claim.
Instead, what I found was the missing step in the proof of the lemma! The idea of splitting a part of a $k$-partite graph in two was used several times to prove bounds; for example, Proposition 5 used the fact that $K(5,2,\dots,2)$ is a subgraph of $K(3,2,2,\dots,2)$ (with one more part). Once I saw that this increases the chromatic number without adding vertices (which is not a particularly hard idea in retrospect, but sometimes easy ideas can still stump you) then I applied it to prove the lemma.
